EXPORT INTO raising syntax errors in AMDP procedure
I am trying to upload the data from SAP tables to GCS Storage bucket and followed the documentation provided in EXPORT INTO Statement (Data Import Export), however when I try to implement the same in AMDP Procedure, it's raising the error the following syntax error. Is it won't work in AMDP procedure or any alternative way we can achieve it?


EXPORT INTO is one of the statements which cannot be used in CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION (what AMDP is about) as you can see in the SAP Library (<proc_stmt_list> ::= <proc_stmt> [ <proc_stmt> [...] ] <proc_stmt> ::= <proc_block> | <proc_assign> | <proc_tabvar_search> ...) Did you try to execute directly in ABAP? (EXEC SQL or ADBC)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

here my requirement is to update the SAP HANA data base table content to GCS Storage  file. I am trying upload the same from AMDP method( ABAP Managed Database Procedure) and used the Export statement which is given sap help documentation ( https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/6a6f59bbfbb64ade84d83d7f87789753.html )
